# Preserve new lines when inserting text into a textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to insert values into a textarea in place of a string. The function is removing any blank lines above the string after replacing it, though. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qH4v4/

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/(?:\s|^)\[image\]/);
var place_image_reference = function(textarea, tag, reference) {
  return textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(pattern, "[image 123]") + reference);
};
```

Basically, the function should find an instance of `[image]` in the text and replace it with `[image 123]`. The regex should only match `[image]` on a new line or preceded by a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you don't replace the preceding delimiter you matched:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/(\s|^)\[image\]/);
var place_image_reference = function(textarea, tag, reference) {
  return textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(pattern, "$1[image 123]") + reference);
};
```

That changes the non-capturing group to a regular (capturing) group, and then the `.replace()` call puts the matched delimiter back.

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the newline-character as well, so just get rid of the preceeding check for a newline.
Use this pattern:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/\[image\]/);
```